# Slick.js как остановить слайд?

Tags: slick.js

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на слайдер он останавливался. С теми настройками, которые сейчас есть, он останавливается, но только тогда, когда слайд завершит свою анимацию. Как сделать так, чтобы слайдер останавливался даже если слад прошел только на половину, то есть слайд так и остается пройденным только на половину.

```
customerSlider.slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 8000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

Comment: pauseOnHover:false / true

Comment: @MaximLensky `pauseOnHover` по дефолту прописан как `true`, он не делает остановку слайда, пока не завершена его анимация.

Comment: почему не делает ? смотри : https://codepen.io/lauriemustafic/pen/MaVjKY

Comment: @MaximLensky Не делает. Для наглядности сделай скорость 8000 (но и на 3000 нормально видно) и наведи курсор на любой слайд, он остановится (так как я и говорил), но не моментально и не просто моментально проскролить до конца слайд и остановится, а нужно чтобы он так сказать мгновенно заморозился, чтобы если во время наведения слайд прошел только на половину, на этой половине он и должен остановиться.